# AngularFire2 How to retrieve records with certain uid's?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have two tables in firebase. First table called **friend_list** and contain the information about current user friends (their uid's). **users** table consist of users display Name, email address and photo URL.

```
users
   --- (uid)
      --- displayName
      --- email
      --- photoURL
```

How can I retrieve information from users table, with specific user ids? Currently I have two friends in a friendlist.
Sorry I'm very newbie in firebase.

Answer (score 1):

you can Get the object from firebase database

in constructor add  `public af: AngularFire,`

in function

```
let uid="xxxx" // here is your user id

let item = this.af.object('/users/' + uid, { preserveSnapshot: true });
      item.subscribe(snapshot => {

        console.log(snapshot.val())
        this.userDetails= snapshot.val();
      });
```

Comment: this.userDetail = snapshot.payload.val(); work for me.